Adding multiple bones that react to physics naturally
I am trying to add tassels to my model, which happens to have many tassels. All of which have bones,  which react to gravity and movement realistically. I was using Wiggle bones, but i noticed that i cannot have these bones collide with themselves properly/realistically without it glitching. On top of that, the model has other accessories that the bones should collide with. I was wondering what other performance friendly way would there be to add many bones that react realistically with each other, and other objects?
(i had asked this question months ago, but i was suggested using cloth sims, but i will be having a lot of other meshes that will have this rig setup, so i dont think it will be performance friendly.)
My actual file is quite heavy and messy, i will clean it up tonight after work and upload it here, but until then if anyone has suggests, i would appreciate it.



Here is the blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/gogzvedxvammzes/Tassel+Troubleshooting.blend/file

For some reason, my descriptions weren't included. The first one is using Bone Dynamics Pro, which makes them act up like this. The last two are with wiggle bones, one being the setup, and the last one is how they look when i press play. It can interact with the cords, but then they group up together, and they are all floating for some reason.
